# Xcode 6.4 Doesn't List Targets or Groups for Project

Tags: xcode

I'm working on a project and went to add a new file, but the Finder window is different than the usual window when adding a file. When I go File->New File->Cocoa Touch Class->Set up name, superclass and language, I get this:

[image: Finder window I get]

This is *only* the case for Objective-C files. For Swift files I get the usual window where I can choose the target membership and Group I want the file to be in

Comment: If you hit create and go to your file in the file inspector on the right pane, do the target memberships area show anything? Sounds like a bug with Xcode 6.4 and OS X El Capitan. My Device Target selection box is missing in Xcode 6.4 and OS X El Capitan

Comment: Hey! Yeah, I can chose the Target Membership that way and that's what I've been doing, but it's really annoying lol. My Device Target selection box was missing for a while too. Then when I updated to beta 3 I got it back. Sigh... Maybe I'll have to live with it until the El Capitan GM (or later beta)

Answer (score 0):

Well this sounds like a great bug to report at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com) . Not much we can do other than wait for the next beta and hope they solve it then.

Comment: Was just in the middle of filing one :) hopefully we'll see a fix soon